# Variable in class name - pug

Tags: html, pug

I need to create div's with class `pixel-1`,`pixel-2`... `pixel-n` and my question is how to achieve it with `pug`. I tried this:

```
- for (var x = 1; x < 13; x++)
      .pixel-x=x
```

but it's generate css like this:

```
<div class="pixel-x">1</div>
<div class="pixel-x">2</div>
<div class="pixel-x">3</div>
...
```

Comment: Are you willing to do this with javascript?

Comment: I have this code in my HTML file. I code on codepen and pug is considered to be a HTML preprocessor there. I know that it would be simple to do with JS but my question is if it is possible to do without it?

Comment: I do not know pug, sorry.... If you need help doing it in another language I could help you.

Comment: If you know another HTML preprocessor that will suits here it will be helpful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
- for (var x = 1; x < 13; x++)
  div(class='pixel-' + x)
```

Comment: Great, this is what I need. Thank you